# Proving the tangent hyperconic of an algebraic hypersurface $V(f)$ is indeed a hyperconic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $V(f)$ is an algebraic hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}P^n$ and $P=[p]\in V(f)$ a point of the algebraic hypersurface with multiplicity $k$. That is to say, all $k-1$ derivitives of $f$ are zero in $p$, and a $k$th derivative of $f$ in $p$ is non-zero.

Then the line $PQ$ through $P$ intersects $V(f)$ with multiplicity strictly greater than $k$ $\textbf{if and only if}$ $Q$ is on the algebraic hyperplane defined by$$\sum_{i_1,\dots,i_k=0}^{n}\dfrac{\partial^kf}{\partial x_{i_1}\dots\partial x_{i_k}}(p)x_{i_1}\dots x_{i_k}=0.$$

It is clearly a hyperplane of degree $k$, and it is called the $\textbf{tangent hyperconic to $V(f)$ in $P$}$.

Call this algebraic hyperplane $H$.

> H is a hyperconic.

Proof: Let $Q\not= P$ be some point in $\mathbb{C}P^n$. Then $Q\in H$ if and only if $PQ$ intersects $V(f)$ with multiplicity greater than $k$. So, the fact that $Q\in H$ depends not so much on $Q$, but rather on the line $PQ$. This means that, if $Q\in H$, then $PQ\subseteq H$. Indeed, some $X\in PQ$ will then lie on a line that interesects $V(f)$ with multiplicity greater than $k$, which means $X\in H$.

$\textbf{Question}$: I cannot seem to prove this fact directly. I.e let $Q\not= P$ be on $H$, take $X\in PQ$ and now show $X\in H$ by showing it satisfies the equation that defines $H$. Some tips?